# Moss Timer job deployed in one web application but running in a different web application

Tags: 2007, timer-jobs, central-administration, web-application

I can't believe Timer Jobs and SharePoint can be this un-predictable.

I deployed my Timer job feature solution to web application A and activated feature, it worked for 3 days in same web application without any kind of problem. Today after nothing at all has been changed other then EVENT RECEIVER failed to load a dll (dunno why tho) and it went to Initialized stage with "0%" progress.

I looked at Solution Management in central Admin and its deployed to web application A

I looked at Timer Job Definition for Web Application A and I can't find definition for Timer job, however we got around 15 Web Applications so I looked at another Web Application let say Web Application B and Timer Job Definition was there.

How strange, I don't even know what exactly to google.

Most people say clear Configuration Cache to make it work, but why would it happen at first place and its our development server I can clear configuration cache but what if it happens on Live, I can't go to Live server and gonna clear Cache whenever this timer job will hang

Comment: Was the timer job referencing the DLL at all do you know, ie was it anything to do with what this Timer job was doing? Or maybe the event receiver firing on something on the job or are they not linked at all?

Comment: they are not linked at all, dll was just for event fire that saves values to DB table, but main concern is why Timer job definition says its in a different web application :S

Comment: Is it a web application scoped timer job?

Comment: yup it is indeed

Comment: I came this morning and timer job is running successfully, no one touched server at all, except the timed operations happens at early morning, but again I am pretty sure non of operation re-configure cache.

Comment: Just watch out for windows events and errors in the uls and keep an eye on it, doesn't seem to be anything else you can achieve without finding the error.

Comment: What is the base class that you are using for your TimerJob?

Comment: I presume the SPJobDefinition class. Are you using the SPWebApplication constructor rather than SPService constructor?

Comment: yup using SPJobDefinition class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it depends on which web application feature you activated it, if you activated it in web application B then Timer job definition will be in Web App B regardless of where it has been deployed, why ? I don't know to be honest.

Comment: let me try but how can you activate a feature that is not deployed to a specific web application

Comment: thanks lot it worked, but am still confused

Comment: glad it worked & for rest gooogle it ;)

Comment: The feature activation will decide which Web Application the Timer job is associated to because when you create your timer job using the SPJobDefinition derived class you pass in the SPWebApplication object into that constructor. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spjobdefinition.spjobdefinition(v=office.12).aspx